# Whiteboard iPad app to interactively teach/hold a lecture

Tags: ios, note-taking, presentation, ipad-app, whiteboard

I will teach children for a week, in a room that only has a projector. No whiteboard or blackboard. I am therefore looking for the best application for an iPad that I can use to draw on interactively, to show them what sort of experiments they will do, the theory behind in, and how they are going to do this.

I mainly need something that functions like a plain whiteboard app, does not need to be fancy. I would appreciate recommendations of good free applications and also some information on what applications are the absolute best for this (regardless of price).

Comment: I would be tempted to buy a whiteboard on an easel at an office supply store.

Comment: Yes I agree, but I still want to get a recommendation on the absolute best software for this - because it might just be very good